# Login Logs - Send email to admin once

Tags: php, pdo

So im in a pickle..

I've created my classes which works fine, as does the sending of the email however, if the user keeps pressing login it'll send the email over and over where it should only send it one time. I have either placed it in the wrong place or I need add something else to it of which I'm a bit lost.

Here's my code:

```
public function login($username, $password)
    {
        if (!empty($username) || !empty($password))
        {
            $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
            $stmt = $this->run("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = ?");
            $stmt->execute([$username]);

            $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            $blocked = $this->run("SELECT count(*) FROM `failedLogins` WHERE `ipAddress` = ?");
            $blocked->execute([$ip]);
            $re = $blocked->fetchColumn();


            $ipBlock = $this->run("SELECT * FROM `blockedIPS` WHERE `ip` = ?");
            $ipBlock->execute([$ip]);

            if ($re <= 6) {
                if ($ipBlock->rowCount() == 0)
                {
                    if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
                        if (password_verify($password, $row['password'])) {
                            $_SESSION['user_session'] = $row['userid'];

                            $stmt = $this->run("UPDATE `users` SET `loginCount` = `loginCount` + 1, `loginIP` = ? WHERE `username` = ?");
                            $stmt->execute([$ip, $username]);

                            $add = $this->run("INSERT INTO `loginLog` (`username`,`ipAddress`, `date`) VALUES (?,?, NOW())");
                            $add->execute([$username, $ip]);
                            $this->redirect('home');

                        } else {
                            $stmt = $this->run("INSERT INTO `failedLogins`(`username`,`password`,`ipAddress`,`when`,`reason`) VALUES (?,?,?,NOW(),'Incorrect Password')");
                            $stmt->execute([$username, $password, $ip]);

                            echo Common::warning('The password you have entered is incorrect');
                        }
                    } else {
                        $stmt = $this->run("INSERT INTO `failedLogins`(`username`,`password`,`ipAddress`,`when`, `reason`) VALUES (?,?,?,NOW(), 'Username guess, possible brute force')");
                        $stmt->execute([$username, $password, $ip]);
                        echo Common::error('This username doesn\'t exist.');
                    }
                } else {
                    Common::emailAdmin("The following IP address has now been blocked from logging in: $ip");
                    echo Common::error('Your IP address has been blocked from accessing our website.');
                }
            } else {
                $stmt = $this->run("INSERT INTO `blockedIPS`(`ip`,`date`) VALUES (?,NOW())");
                $stmt->execute([$ip]);

                echo Common::error('You have tried to log in too many times incorrectly. Your account has now been frozen.');
            }
        } else {
            echo Common::warning('Please fill in both fields.');
        }
    }
```

Chances are i've misplaced it but a second pair of eyes to glance over and tell me where i've messed up would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would remove the `else` part of the code:

```
else {
    Common::emailAdmin("The following IP address has now been blocked from logging in: $ip");
    echo Common::error('Your IP address has been blocked from accessing our website.');
}
```

And move the email line into the `else` where you update `blockedIPS`, e.g.:

```
$stmt = $this->run("INSERT INTO `blockedIPS`(`ip`,`date`) VALUES (?,NOW())");
$stmt->execute([$ip]);

echo Common::error('You have tried to log in too many times incorrectly. Your account has now been frozen.');

Common::emailAdmin("The following IP address has now been blocked from logging in: $ip");
```

Since this is where you are actually blocking the IP, it makes to send the email at this stage.

Also, you are not actually blocking the blockedIPS from attempting to login again, you should make sure you prevent these IPs from logging in, regardless of failed attempts.

E.g.

```
if ($ipBlock->rowCount() >= 1) {
  // IP has been blocked already
  echo Common::error('You have tried to log in too many times incorrectly. Your account has now been frozen.');
  // prevent further access
} else {
 // do the rest, including blocking IP here
}
```

Comment: Seems to of done the trick :) I thought I might have over done it with the block side of things on the if statements! Now blending this in with the initial, im allowing the failed passwords to go in un encrypted.. Usually I wouldn't but would you advise against it?

Comment: Wouldn't recommend it, since you are essentially creating a database of password that didn't work. Should the information ever get leaked, you've just provided a list of passwords that don't need to be attempted, and thus reducing the time for someone to brute-force the correct one.

Comment: Very true there! I'll hash it in that instance or even remove i guess as it's not desperately required, was more of a log. Thanks again!